# Why can a default template be necessary for template deduction?

Tags: c++, templates

I am writing a generic [branch and bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_and_bound) algorithm using templates, in C++17.

The code compiles (and runs) fine when I supply the default template argument RealFun2 = RealFun1:

```
template <typename Repr, typename SplFun, typename Predicate, 
        typename RealFun1, typename RealFun2=RealFun1>
optional<Repr> branch_and_bound(Repr r0, SplFun split, Predicate goal, 
        RealFun1 F, RealFun2 lower_bound) {
    optional<Repr> BEST; 
    float F_BEST = INFINITY; 
    stack<Repr> ACTIVE; ACTIVE.push(r0); 
    while(!ACTIVE.empty()) {
        Repr r = ACTIVE.top(); ACTIVE.pop(); 
        if(goal(r)) {
            if(F(r) < F_BEST) {
                BEST = r; 
                F_BEST = F(r); 
            }
        }
        else
            for(Repr q: split(r))
                if(lower_bound(q) < F_BEST)
                    ACTIVE.push(q); 
    }
    return BEST; 
}


struct knapsack { /* ... */ }; 
using Repr = pair<knapsack, vector<int>>; 
bool goal(Repr r) { /* ... */ }
float F(Repr r) { /* ... */ }
vector<Repr> split(Repr r) { /* ... */ }
float lower_bound(Repr r) { /* ... */ } 

int main() {
    // ...
    knapsack K(N, cap, weight, value); 
    Repr r0(K, vector<int>(N, 0)); 
    optional<Repr> BEST = branch_and_bound(r0, split, goal, F, lower_bound); 
   // ...
}
```

However, g++ (7.3.0) complains that it cannot deduce the template parameter RealFun2 if I do not give the default:

```
template <typename Repr, typename SplFun, typename Predicate, 
        typename RealFun1, typename RealFun2>
// rest of code is the same

KNAPBB.cpp:105:72: error: no matching function for call to ‘branch_and_bound(Repr&, std::vector<std::pair<knapsack, std::vector<int> > > (&)(Repr), bool (&)(Repr), float (&)(Repr), <unresolved overloaded function type>)’
optional<Repr> BEST = branch_and_bound(r0, split, goal, F, lower_bound);
BRABOUND.cpp:11:16: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
KNAPBB.cpp:105:72: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter ‘RealFun2’
optional<Repr> BEST = branch_and_bound(r0, split, goal, F, lower_bound);
```

I do not understand the circumstances under which supplying a default should be necessary or not.

Comment: Please try to create a [mcve] to show us. And please copy-paste the full and complete error (as text) into the question.

Comment: You should at least show us the call to the function to get a better idea

Comment: simpler example: `template <typename T> void f();` and then `f();` -> no chance to deduce the parameter vs `template <typename T = int> void f();` and `f();` -> no need to deduce the template parameter. You really need to show us how you call the method

Comment: I added some context. What puzzles me most is that although the functions F() and lower_bound() have the same signature, RealFun2 requires a default while RealFun1 does not.

Answer (score 2):

So, on to the first part of the error message

```
no matching function for call to ‘branch_and_bound(Repr&,
std::vector<std::pair<knapsack, std::vector<int> > > (&)(Repr), bool(&)(Repr), float (&)(Repr), <unresolved overloaded function type>)’
```

The part *unresolved overloaded function type>* marks the parameter where you pass `lower_bound`. It means that there are more functions with that name and the compiler can't decide which one you mean.

There are [`std::lower_bound`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound) functions in `<algorithm>` header, which means you've got `using namespace std;` somewhere.

It should now be obvious why it works when there's default for the last template parameter - the compiler doesn't have to guess the type.

Answer (score 1):

The problem turns out to be the name of the function, in the function definition `float lower_bound(Repr)`. Unfortunately, `lower_bound` clashes with a function from the Standard Library in `<algorithm>`. Without the template default, the compiler had not enough information to distinguish between the user-provided function and the standard library one.

Comment: you have a `using namespace std;` somewhwere? take it as a lesson :P

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice